# How to run and interact with a program such as "bash -c ssh ..." using swift 4 and playgrounds?

Tags: swift, bash, ssh, process, swift-playground

How can one run and interact with a program such as ssh in a bash terminal using swift 4 and playgrounds?  Terminal commands can be executed in a Mac swift playground with code such as:

```
@discardableResult func shell(_ command: String) -> String {
let task = Process()

task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
task.arguments = ["-c", command]

let pipe = Pipe()

task.standardOutput = pipe
task.launch()

let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()

let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String

return output
}

// Example usage:
let t = shell("ls")
print("\(t)") //prints dir listing
```

However, I would like to be able to interact with programs like ssh versus a programs that aren't interactive such as ls.  For example the command:

```
let t = shell("ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -T -l root -p 22")
```

will start ssh and ssh will via terminal prompt for the password. I want to be able to then programmatically provide the password and continue.  It seems to me that since SSH is running in the context of terminal that highjacking terminals stdin and stdout should suffice however, I've not been successful with that so far.  Here are some resources I found that provide some information on highjacking:

[Big nerd on highjacking](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/hijacking-for-fun-and-profit/)

[Medium article](https://medium.com/@thesaadismail/eavesdropping-on-swifts-print-statements-57f0215efb42)

Any ideas about if and how this could be accomplished?

Comment: updated the summary a bit as it's not really *bash terminal*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh` reads passwords directly from `/dev/tty` rather than `stdin`. To programmatically control a tty you need the *pty* module/APIs which tools like [Expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expect) are using.

I know nothing about Swift so not sure if it has a similar *pty* module. If it does not then you can use [Expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expect) to run `ssh`.